# C++ function argument, int short

Tags: c++

When I only use short integers in my program, is it better to use:

```
void printVars(int x1, int x2, int x3)
```

or

```
void printVars(short int x1, short int x2, short int x3)
```

as argument for my functions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: better in what sense?

Comment: Why does your program only use short? Do you know how its speed is affected by using `short` rather than `int`? Do you have so much data that you absolutely must do this in order to fit it into memory? Don't forget, `int` is the "natural" size for the architecture, so unless you're constrained by memory, there isn't a good reason to use `short`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are 100% sure you will never use bigger integers than short int, it's better to use it as it might save 2 bytes (in most of the cases, on most systems, but not necessarily). It's indeed always a god idea to not use more resources than you need
The difference would probably be neglectable with mot applications though.

Comment: It **might** save two bytes. An `int` is required to be no smaller than a `short`, but it does not have to be larger.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use `short`s then there is no harm in passing `short` function parameters, as you won't lose anything, but it won't save much in terms of memory footprint or performance by using `short`s at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emphasize on the allowed range of values, I'ld prefer the `short int`. This saves space and it makes clear/better readable what the allowed values are.

`int` might be better in sense of performance, but I'ld not count on that.

My advice: if you are sure that `short int` is the type with the best matching range, then use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `short` so your code is more consisntent. Also it's better to make a `typedef` in case you would like to change your type in future. Just make `typedef short int Short` and use it in your program. Later you will be able to change the `Short` type just in a single place

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to do with your parameters is to communicate what your function needs as input and will produce as output.  If your function will only work on numbers in the range of short then use `short` for your type.  What you have to ask is what would happen if you allowed numbers that are greater than the maximum value for short?  Is that an error?

The performance impact of passing shorts or ints is likely to be negligible or non-existent.  Don't worry about performance unless it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question can only be truly answered by running tests on the computer that you're going to run on.

On my modern Intel Ubuntu (2017), speed differences are down in the noise.  Pushing shorts onto the stack seems to be just a hair 1% faster than pushing ints onto the stack, +/- about 1%.

Most of the speedup is going to come from cutting your memory in half, which will save page-swapping on those big-data / neural-net munging programs.